# CSV geodata into elasticsearch as a geo_point type using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Below is a reproducible example of the problem I am having using to most recent versions of logstash and elasticsearch.

I am using logstash to input geospatial data from a csv into elasticsearch as geo_points.

The CSV looks like the following:

```
$ head simple_base_map.csv 
"lon","lat"
-1.7841,50.7408
-1.7841,50.7408
-1.78411,50.7408
-1.78412,50.7408
-1.78413,50.7408
-1.78414,50.7408
-1.78415,50.7408
-1.78416,50.7408
-1.78416,50.7408
```

I have create a mapping template that looks like the following:

```
$ cat simple_base_map_template.json 
{
  "template": "base_map_template",
  "order":    1,
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },

      "mappings": {
        "node_points" : {
          "properties" : {
            "location" : { "type" : "geo_point" }
          }
        }
      }
}
```

and have a logstash config file that looks like the following:

```
$ cat simple_base_map.conf 
input {
  stdin {}
}

filter {
  csv {
      columns => [
        "lon", "lat"
      ]
  }

  if [lon] == "lon" {
      drop { }
  } else {
      mutate {
          remove_field => [ "message", "host", "@timestamp", "@version"     ]
      }
       mutate {
          convert => { "lon" => "float" }
          convert => { "lat" => "float" }
          }

      mutate {
          rename => {
              "lon" => "[location][lon]"
              "lat" => "[location][lat]"
          }
      }
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => dots }
  elasticsearch {
      index => "base_map_simple"
      template => "simple_base_map_template.json"
      document_type => "node_points"
  }
}
```

I then run the following:

```
$cat simple_base_map.csv | logstash-2.1.3/bin/logstash -f simple_base_map.conf 
Settings: Default filter workers: 16
Logstash startup completed
....................................................................................................Logstash shutdown completed
```

However when looking at the index base_map_simple, it suggests the documents would not have a location: geo_point type in it...and rather it would be two doubles of lat and lon.

```
$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/base_map_simple?pretty'
{
  "base_map_simple" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "node_points" : {
        "properties" : {
          "location" : {
            "properties" : {
              "lat" : {
                "type" : "double"
              },
              "lon" : {
                "type" : "double"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1457355015883",
        "uuid" : "luWGyfB3ToKTObSrbBbcbw",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "2020099"
        }
      }
    },
    "warmers" : { }
  }
}
```

How would i need to change any of the above files to ensure that it goes into elastic search as a geo_point type?

Finally, I would like to be able to carry out a nearest neighbour search on the geo_points by using a command such as the following:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/base_map_simple/_search?pretty' -d'
{
    "size": 1,
    "sort": {
   "_geo_distance" : {
       "location" : {
            "lat" : 50,
            "lon" : -1
        },
        "order" : "asc",
        "unit": "m"
   } 
    }
}'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in your `elasticsearch` output you named the index `base_map_simple` while in your template the `template` property is `base_map_template`, hence the template is not being applied when creating the new index. The `template` property [needs to somehow match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) the name of the index being created in order for the template to kick in.

It will work if you simply change the latter to `base_map_*`, i.e. as in:

```
{
  "template": "base_map_*",             <--- change this
  "order": 1,
  "settings": {
    "index.number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "node_points": {
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Make sure to delete the current index as well as the template first., i.e.

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/base_map_simple
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/_template/logstash
```

Comment: I get the following error ```Unexpected character ('"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries
 at [Source: [B@41132e21; line: 12, column: 9] {:class=>"LogStash::Json::ParserError", :level=>:error}``` when running logstash

Comment: Weird, it works fine on my end. Are you sure that you copy/pasted the above template (and removed the `<--- change this` characters)?

Comment: Also note that you need to delete the current index as well as the template first., i.e. `curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/base_map_simple` + `curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/_template/logstash`

Comment: Ah, thanks but after adjusting as suggested the result of running the request ```curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/base_map_simple?pretty'``` it results the same results as suggested in the question...

Comment: Can you show what you get with `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_template`?

Comment: Ah yes, it looks like I had to delete the template and index as well, it now works! thanks!

Comment: @val I did what you said and whats written in above question.
I am getting this error. 

"status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"[location] is defined as an object in mapping [log] but this name is already used for a field in other types"

Comment: @JaspinderVirdee that's another issue, feel free to create a new question for it.