# Logstash - Send output from log files to elk

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have an index in elastic search that has a field named locationCoordinates. It's being sent to ElasticSearch from logstash.

The data in this field looks like this...

```
-38.122, 145.025
```

When this field appears in ElasticSearch it is not coming up as a geo point.

I know if I do this below it works.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "logs": {
      "properties": {
        "http_request.locationCoordinates": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But what I would like to know is how can i change my logstash.conf file so that it does this at startup.

At the moment my logstash.conf looks a bit like this...

```
input {

    # Default GELF input
    gelf {
        port => 12201
        type => gelf
    }

    # Default TCP input
    tcp {
        port => 5000
        type => syslog
    }

    # Default UDP input
    udp {
        port => 5001
        type => prod
        codec => json
    }
    file {
       path =>  [ "/tmp/app-logs/*.log" ]
       codec =>   json {
          charset => "UTF-8"
       }
       start_position => "beginning"
       sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
   }
}

filter {
   json{
      source => "message"
   }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
    }
}
```

And I end up with this in Kibana (without the little Geo sign).

[image]

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844409/csv-geodata-into-elasticsearch-as-a-geo-point-type-using-logstash/35894544#35894544

Comment: Hi @Val. Thanks for responding. Yes, I've seen that post but that still doesn't make it all that clear for me. I've tried something based on that post but I think i need it bit more clarity if possible.

Comment: Fair enough. Can you add your `elasticsearch` output configuration to your question?

Comment: What did you want to see from es? elasticsearch.yml?

Comment: The `elasticsearch` output configuration is from your logstash configuration (below the filters)

Comment: oh ok. Added my complete logstash.conf above which include the es output config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to modify your `elasticsearch` output to configure an index template in which you can add your additional mapping.

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        template_overwrite => true
        template => "/path/to/template.json"
    }
}
```

And then in the file at `/path/to/template.json` you can add your additional `geo_point` mapping

```
{
  "template": "logstash-*",
  "mappings": {
    "logs": {
      "properties": {
        "http_request.locationCoordinates": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to keep the official logstash template, you can [download it](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/blob/f4cf5b67b6776d847df32f38d4fd95f835e109e0/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template-es2x.json) and add your specific `geo_point` mapping to it.

Comment: I'd love to be able to say that worked but it didn't. I am getting messages in the logs telling me "{"template":"logstash-*","mappings":{"logs":{"properties":{"http_response.locationCoordinates":{"type":"geo_point"}}}}}". But i can't get it to work. I will continue tomorrow.

Comment: Can you run this and update your question with what you get? `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_template/logstash`

Comment: Also you might need to delete your logstash index which has the `http_request.locationCoordinates` field with the wrong string mapping. The new template I provided will only kick in at the next index creation unless you delete today's logstash index so it gets recreated from the new template.

Comment: Hi @Val Thanks for getting back to me. In regards to your last comment doesn't the setting sincedb_path => "/dev/null" take care of deleting and recreating the index each time logstash starts up?

Comment: No, setting `sincedb_path` to `/dev/null` will simply re-read the log file from the beginning each time logstash starts, that's all, but it has no influence whatsoever on your `elasticsearch` output.

Comment: Ok so I did that then restarted. It doesn't seem like it is working bc the little geo sign is still not next to my co-ordinates in kibana. Bizarre observation though. When I apply the index to http_request.locationCoordinates it turns to attribute to http_response.locationCoordinates. But when I comment out the template it changes it back to http_request.locationCoordinates. Oh man this is confusing. Thanks for your help

Comment: You need to make sure that your index is properly recreated, then you need to refresh the fields in your index pattern for that index in Kibana.